# Can't use "continue <label>"

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, continue

I am trying this code:

```
entLoop:for(var i:*in entities) {
    for(var i2:*in ignoreEntities) {
        if(entities[i].type==ignoreEntities[i2]) {
            continue entLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it not working? The error is:

Target of continue statement was not found.

Comment: A discussion about the problem: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=766215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems that the `continue` instruction doesn't work with `for...in` loops.

Compiler doesn't throw any error with this code :

```
entLoop:for(var i:Number = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
  for(var i2:Number = 0 ; i2 < 2 ; i2++) {
    if(true) {
      continue entLoop;
    }
  }
}
```

(I replaced your condition by `true` since I don't have the definitions for your `entities` and `ignoreEntities` arrays)

Comment: Seems I was right, if I believe this link : http://blog.coursevector.com/notes-loopstatement-labels : "If you’re going to use labels, you’ll want to make sure you’re using regular for or while loops. (A bug has been filed and will hopefully be fixed soon.)" - posted in January 2010

Comment: That's so wrong, continue shouldn't be used in this case, just check the actionscript reference (it's the same for most languages) http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use `break LABEL;` instead.

From live docs :
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html

Comment: Do u know the difference between "continue" and "break"?

Comment: well break; "breaks" out of the loop whereas continue; "continues" (i.e. jumps) to a label.

Comment: Do u know the difference between "continue", "break" and "goto"?

Comment: I'm super curious now, please explain instead of minus pointing :(, I must have got missed out something for a long time.